# How to resolve request mapping "ambiguous" situation in spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have written a spring controller in which I just wanted to use a single URL for all methods.
Even if I am using different method signature **int, string, object** i am getting error.

```
@RequestMapping(value="problemAPI/ticket", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public @ResponseBody String getTicketData(@RequestParam("customerId") int customerId) {
    return "customer Id: " + customerId + " has active Ticket:1010101";
}

@RequestMapping(value="problemAPI/ticket", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public @ResponseBody String getTicketStatusByCustname(@RequestParam("customerName") String customerName) {  
    return "Mr." + customerName + " Your Ticket is Work in Progress";
}

@RequestMapping(value="problemAPI/ticket", method = RequestMethod.POST )
public @ResponseBody String saveTicket(@RequestBody TicketBean bean) {
    return "Mr." + bean.getCustomerName() + " Ticket" +  bean.getTicketNo() + " has been submitted successfuly";
}
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'problemTicketController' bean method 
public String com.nm.controller.webservice.ticket.problem.ProblemTicketController.getTicketData(int)
to {[/problemAPI/ticket],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'problemTicketController' bean method
public java.lang.String com.nm.controller.webservice.ticket.problem.ProblemTicketController.getTicketByCustname(int) mapped.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can achieve this by explicitly specifying query parameters with `params` annotation property:

```java
@RequestMapping(
    value  = "problemAPI/ticket",
    params = "customerId",
    method = RequestMethod.GET
)
public @ResponseBody String getTicketData(
    @RequestParam("customerId") int customerId
){
    return "customer Id: " + customerId + " has active Ticket:1010101";
}

@RequestMapping(
    value  = "problemAPI/ticket",
    params = "customerName",
    method = RequestMethod.GET
)
public @ResponseBody String getTicketStatusByCustomerName(
    @RequestParam("customerName") String customerName
){
    return "Mr." + customerName + " Your Ticket is Work in Progress";
}
```

To make it cleaner you can use alias annotations like `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping`:

```java
@GetMapping(
    value  = "problemAPI/ticket",
    params = "customerName"
)
public @ResponseBody String getTicketStatusByCustname(
    @RequestParam("customerName") String customerName
) {
    return "Mr." + customerName + " Your Ticket is Work in Progress";
}

@PostMapping(
    value = "problemAPI/ticket"
)
public @ResponseBody String saveTicket(@RequestBody TicketBean bean) {
    return "Mr." + bean.getCustomerName() + " Ticket" +  bean.getTicketNo() + " has been submitted successfuly";
}
```

Comment: What if you have multiple @RequestParam parameters?

Comment: @pixel [`RequestMapping.params`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#params()) is an array. You can pass several param names there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer mentioned by https://stackoverflow.com/users/5091346/andrii-abramov is correct. However the JSR-311 specifications for RESTful services mentions what is written below :

Such methods, known as sub-resource methods, are treated like a normal resource method (see section 3.3) except the method is only invoked for request URIs that match a URI template created by concatenating the URI template of the resource class with the URI template of the method.

Though, with spring framework we can achieve this.